# Can’t run PHPUnit with Composer on Travis-CI, class not found

Tags: php, composer-php, travis-ci

I need some help with a problem. I'm trying to execute a simple build with tests on Travis-CI, but its error, saying that it could not found Class:

> Fatal error: Class 'com\bitshammer\collection\utils\CollectionUtils' not found in /home/travis/build/BitsHammer/CollectionUtils/test/CollectionUtilsTest.php on line 20

Just for your knowledge, it’s my first project using Composer! What I am doing wrong? Do you guys have any idea? Thanks!

- [Travis-CI page](https://travis-ci.org/BitsHammer/CollectionUtils/jobs/171248224)
- [Project page on GitHub](https://github.com/BitsHammer/CollectionUtils)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your namespaces are wrong for the autoloading.

In `composer.json`, your autoloading maps the namespace `com\bitshammer\` to `src/`.

You currently have the namespace at `com\bitshammer\collection\utils` which means your file path for this class would instead needs to be `src/collection/utils/CollectionUtils.php` instead of `src/CollectionUtils.php`.

Alternatively you could change the namespace for this class to be `com\bitshammer` instead of `com\bitshammer\collection\utils`.

Comment: I have changed the class location to src/collection/utils as you said, but it still not working.. Same error

Comment: thanks for your help! Your answer was correct, I just changed what you said and changed psr-0 to psr-4!